# Chrome Extension: How to add custom JS and CSS into a website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to develop a chrome extension and add my custom CSS and JS;
I have these Two files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Block request",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
       "js": ["content_script.js"]
}],

  "permissions": [
      "webRequest",
      "webRequestBlocking",
      "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
if (window.location.hostname = "w3schools.com") {
    alert("Hello");
    console.log("Hi console");
}
```

I added this extension to the Chrome, but when I refresh every page I got *alert* message;
How can I solve this issue?
Is my coding correct?

Comment: You forgot a few equal signs `if (window.location.hostname === "w3schools.com") {`
Please read about [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Thank you @dporechny; but with 3 equals , extension doesn't work at all.

Comment: Yep that's not because of equals, that's because `window.location.hostname` for w3schools returns `www.w3schools.com`. Try with `www.` and it'll work.

Comment: @dporechny it works in Chrome developer tools section (console); but when I upload my file as an extension to the Chrome; it doesn't work; Maybe this is not the correct structure for chrome extension!

Comment: I tried your codes with these modification `if (window.location.hostname === "www.w3schools.com")`, and they worked fine, so what's really the problem? Do you get any error?

Comment: Make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.